# A strange (!) behaviour of differentiability

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I see by drawing diagram that $y=\max (0,\sin x)$ is not differentiable at some points. But $y=(\max (0,\sin x)) ^ 2$ is . How to explain/prove it ? Am I missing something easy ?

If $f$ is not differentiable at $x$ and $g$ is differentiable then $g\circ f$ differentiable at $x$ ?

Comment: For a simpler example of the same phenomenon, notice that $y=|x|$ is not differentiable at $0$, but $y=|x|^2$ is...

Comment: @Micah: yes, but how to prove it. What is the general theorem we have to use ?

Comment: There is no general theorem. Non-differentiability of a function $f$ has nothing to do with the differentiability properties of $f^2$. However, if $f$ is differentiable then so is $f^2$ - this might be what is confusing you.

Comment: It's similar to the fact that $y = |x|$ is not differentiable at $x=0$ but $y = |x|^2$ (which is the same as $y = x^2)$ is differentiable at $x=0.$ Or perhaps better, it's like what happens when you square the function $f(x)$ defined to be $x$ when $x \geq 0$ and defined to be $0$ when $x < 0.$ Note that near $x=0$ the graph of $y = \max\{0, \, \sin {x} \}$ looks like the graph of the function I just defined (think about linearizations to the right and left of $x = 0).$

Comment: One "general theorem" is that if the values of the function approach $0$ at least as fast as $|x-a|^a$ (where $a$ is some real number greater than $1),$ then the function will have a zero derivative at $x=a.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a function is defined piecewise, as
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}g(x) & & {\text{if }} x\ge0 \\
h(x) & & {\text{if }}x<0,
\end{cases}
$$
where $g$ and $h$ are differentiable, its derivative exists at the join point if and only if its pieces have the same derivative there (i.e., $g'(0)=h'(0)$).  That is, the join must be *smooth*.  In your example, the derivative of $\sin x$ where it crosses $0$ is $\cos x=\pm\sqrt{1-\sin^2 x}=\pm 1$, so the joins are not smooth.  The derivative of $\sin^2 x$ at the same locations is $2\sin x \cos x=0$, so the joins are smooth.

Comment: is this true that  for any $f$ non-differentiable at $x$, $g$ differentiable and $g \circ f$ being differentiable ? if not which conditions are sufficient ?

Comment: @user148951 There is a chain rule for left- and right- derivatives. That is, if $L$ is the left derivative operator and $R$ is the right derivative operator then $L(g \circ f)(x) = L(g)(f(x)) L(f)(x)$ and $R(g \circ f)(x) = R(g)(f(x)) R(f(x))$. Thus if $f$ is left- and right-differentiable at $x$ and $g'(f(x))=0$ then $g \circ f$ is differentiable at $x$ with derivative 0.

Comment: @mjqxxxx The derivative of $\sin(x)$ is $1$ at $0$. This is the right derivative of the piecewise function. The left derivative is $0$, from the constant piece. There's no $-1$ anywhere.

Comment: @Ian: The function he named was $\max(0, \sin x)$.  This has multiple join points (at each position where $\sin x=0$).  The derivative of $\sin x$ is $+1$ at some of those points and $-1$ at the rest.

Comment: Ah, my mistake, I assumed it was looking at a small neighborhood of zero for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

The derivative is a limit.  Check the two one-sided limits for the two functions.
For example, with the first function,

$$\lim_{x\to 0-}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to 0-}\frac{0}{x}=0\\
\lim_{x\to 0+}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}-\lim_{x\to0+}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$$

The two limits are different, so the limit doesn't exist; so the derivative does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

One little picture says more than a long speech!

On the blue curve there is an angular point at $y=0$. Of course, the corresponding function is not derivable at this point.

At the same point, the red curve is tangent to the x-axe. So, the corresponding function is derivable because the derivatives have the same limit $=0$ on the left and right sides.

It is the same if the angular point is anywhere on the x-axe. On can understand that it is a general property for any angular point located on the x-axe.

[image]